# How to populate two child member variables of same pojo type in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have one parent table with composite primary key (`idOne`, `idTwo`):

```
Parent table 
-----------------
idOne |  idTwo |......other columns
-----------------
1     | 11191
2     | 11191
```

And one child table.Child table key consist of (`idOne`, `idTwo`, `child_type`):

```
Child table
------------------------------------------
idOne      |  idTwo         | child_type .......other columns
-------------------------------------------
1          |  11191         | typeOne
2          |  11191         | typeTwo
```

The POJO structure is bit different. Parent POJO has two variable of reference type `Child`. Below is the `Parent` POJO structure

```
Parent 
------------
Child typeOneChild;
Child typeTwoChild;
```

So while retrieving the data from DB and populating the parent pojo, I also need to populate the `typeOneChild` and `typeTwoChild` pojos, based on the `child_type` column value. If the `child_type` column value is `typeOne`, then *this row will be used for populate the `typeOneChild` pojo* and for column value `typeTwo`, *it will populate the `typeTwoChild`*.

So basically when I will retrieve the parent details it should execute the below sqls:

```
Select * from parent table where idOne=1 and idTwo=11191;

Select * from child table where idOne=1 and idTwo=11191 and child_type= 'typeOne'

Select * from child table where idOne=1 and idTwo=11191 and child_type= 'typeTwo'
```

I know in normal scenario, the table and pojo structure is not as expected but we cannot change the table and model structure. So please tell me how can I achieve this in hibernate?

Comment: see here mapping documentation : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/fr-FR/html/mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a Single Table Inheritance strategy with a discriminator column which will look like the below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="child_type")
@Table(name="CHILD")
public abstract class Child {

    @OneToOne
    //specify the join here
    private Parent parent;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("typeOne")
public class TypeOneChild extends Child {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("typeTwo")
public class TypeTwoChild extends Child {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent)
    private TypeOneChild typeOneChild;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent)
    private TypeTwoChild typeTwoChild;
}
```